# Simple combinatorics formula

Tags: combinatorics

i am having some trouble trying to understand this simple formula: 
$\frac{n!}{\left(n-r!\right)r!}$

Even though i am able to solve exercises easily using this formula i can't understand it. How was this formula derived? Is it possible to understand the formula or is it just the result of some certain mathematical work? 
The part that i don't understant is how does diving the possible combinations by the redundancies result in the possible number of arragements of something ignoring order.

Comment: By the rule of product, the number of permutations of $r$ objects from $n$ objects is given by $n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)$ which is the same as $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. Now, since we have counted permutations rather than selections (those ignoring order), we need to see how much overcounting we have done. Notice that we've selected each distinct selection $(a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_r)$ exactly $r!$ times since $r$ objects can be permuted in $r!$ ways. Hence, we divide $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ by $r!$ to get $\dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}=\dbinom nr$ which is the number of ways to select $r$ objects from $n$ objects.

Comment: thanks but the part that i dont understand is why we have to divide by r!, and not just subtract the number of redundancies.   @PrasunBiswas

Comment: If you count every single apple as $4$ apples and get the end result to be $40$ apples, how many apples do you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's a rearrangement and simplification of a binomial coefficient. `http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html`